# C++ code crashes when ran

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    freopen("DATA3.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("DATA33.txt","w",stdout);
    int k;
    string name,costume;
    for(int z = 0; z < 5;z++)
    {
        cin >> k;
        vector<string> friends;
        vector<string> costumes;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < k; i++)
        {
            cin >> name >> costume;
            bool found = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < costumes.size();j++)
            {
                if (costumes[i] == costume) found = true;
            }
            if (found)
                friends.push_back(name);
            else
                costumes.push_back(costume);

        }
        if (!costumes.size()) cout << "SPOOKY\n";
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < costumes.size();i++)
            {
                if ( i == costumes.size())
                    cout << costumes[i];
                else
                    cout << costumes[i] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Whenever i try to run this code it says 3.exe has stopped working. Why is this? I've checked the text files and everythings fine. Anynoe interested in the actual context of the problem http://www.dwite.ca/questions/costume_party.html

Comment: You used a debugger, right?

Comment: Why do you use `freopen` on file's you didn't open in the first place?

Comment: Not in your example. Moreover, is there any reasons you don't use the C++ version (ifstream)?

Comment: There were no specific reasons, but ill try

Comment: Edit with your newest code. Furthermore your algorithm is broken, a costume will never be added: costumes is firstly empty so you never enter the j loop. And you mess up costumes[i] with costumes[j]. Whatever, lay down your algo on paper and check for corner cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (costumes[i] == costume) // You are iterating through j=0 to costumes.size(), so change it to if (costumes[j] == costume).